# Calling UILocalNotification from Main.m

Tags: ios, objective-c, program-entry-point, uilocalnotification

I'm not sure if this is possible but I'm trying to fire a UILocalNotification from a function running on Main.m. So far I tried a couple of different ways but I'm a bit confused on who must present the notification because the simple way doesn't seem to work:
I call this code from a static function called by an Observer (defined in Main.m) on CTTelephonyCenter

```
      UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
      if (localNotif) {
          NSLog(@"Ciao");
          localNotif.alertBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                                        @"La telefonata é finitá!!!!!"];
          localNotif.alertAction = NSLocalizedString(@"Read Message", nil);
          localNotif.soundName = @"alarmsound.caf";
          localNotif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;
          [[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:localNotif];

       }
```

Now, the Log  shows up but localNotif doesn't. 
Is it just how I'm afraid, and I just can't do it from a static function called by Main because the window is not defined?

I know I shouldn't mess around with main.m

Comment: The app is ostensibly running when this happens right? Are you handling notifications in your AppDelegate?

Comment: Notifications will only be shown to the user when your app is in the background.

Comment: Yes the app is running in background in Voip mode. And the notifications are not handled in any way… the notification should present itself instantly… But probably I'm missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try implementing:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification;
```

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

in your application delegate.

If your app is open you can log things here, but notification center wont present anything. Notifications only show up in notification center if your app is in the background.

Comment: my App is in backGround in voip mode. I'll give it a try.

Comment: It's not working but probably because I have a CFRunLoopRun() in Main that blocks everything

Comment: well, I tried without loop and it does work!. The problem is that I'm working on the Main.m because I need that Loop, for now I'll mark this answer as correct, if I find other solutions I'll post them here.